# Mongoose populate not returning proper expected result

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am struct at one point, what i am doing is like using populate for getting data from two tables in Nodejs-mongodb using mongoose:

```
exports.allProperties = async function (req, res) {
    let categoryList = [];
    let propertyList = [];
    let usersIds = [];
    let category_filter = {};
    let filters = {};
    console.log("welcome to allProperties");
    let properties = await Property.find({}).populate({path: 'Category'}).populate('User').exec();
    console.log(properties);
    process.exit();
});
```

The result i have attached as screenshot. Problem is that result should return user object as we are using populate and object id are proper. I am not getting where is the issue but need help if anyone can help me.
[image]

Comment: You should provide `Property` mongoose model schema

Comment: try this `Property.find({}).populate({path: 'user'}).populate('category').exec()` and if doesn't work then please post your schema code

Comment: I have make it correct as per the above suggestions but now it returns only objectid insted of whole data of user.